# How can I make a sidebar scrollbar as the one in Facebook

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make scrollbars like the one for the sidebar in Facebook?
I would like to make a scrollbar using only css, the thumb should be narrower than the track, and visible when hovering over, all the examples that I can find are thumbs wider than tracks, the browser that I use is chrome, below you can find a video of the facebook scrollbar that I was refering.

[facebook sidebar scrollbar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkqutfhmwc7bbrt/20221002_211635.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. what have you tried yourself so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Answer (score 0):

CSS has a built in scrollbar styling. Use webkit-scrollbar for the width, webkit-scrollbar-track for the track,  webkit-scrollbar-thumb for the thumb and you can add any hover properties to the webkit-scrollbar-thumb.
Below is the code that will make the scrollbar almost like facebook's.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border: none;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #d1cece; 
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background: darkgray; 
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, and I can't see where would the scrollbar track be wider than the scrollbar thumb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).